# Load scanned QR url into android webview

Tags: android, webview

**See bottom for the fix to below question**

Ok everything works except for loading the url and when it tries to load the url into the webview it adds url: in front of the hyperlink. For example: url:http://google.com and the webview won't load this of course. I have tried .replace("url:","") and .replaceAll("url:","") to no success. The SCAN_RESULT is generated using zbar barcode library.

Main Activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
        case ZBAR_QR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String value = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT);
                String newValue = value.replaceAll("url:", "");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mUrl",newValue);
                startActivity(intent);

                //Toast.makeText(this, "Scan Result = " + data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
                String error = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.ERROR_INFO);
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(error)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Webview Activity

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String mUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("mUrl");
    //String newMUrl = mUrl.replaceAll("url:", "");

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

}
```

WebView Client

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
}
```

**MainActivity (FIXED)**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
        case ZBAR_QR_SCANNER_REQUEST:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String value = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT);
                //The FIX IS BELOW url is case-sensitive, instead of url: it's URL:
                String newValue = value.replace("URL:", "");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mUrl",newValue);
                startActivity(intent);

                //Toast.makeText(this, "Scan Result = " + data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
                String error = data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.ERROR_INFO);
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(error)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the issue as the url: is actually case sensitive once I step debugged it. On the device it is displayed as a lowercase url: but inside the actual code it's uppercase URL: I hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you don't have to put the following code in **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**, because returning true tells WebView the URL will be handled by the following code. i.e. WebView will not load the URL at all.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
return true;
```

So if you want the URL to be opened in your webview, just simply call **return false** in **shouldOverrideUrlLoading**, unless you want to launch another App (like Android stock Browser) to open the URL.

Comment: Thank you for that fix as I needed to address that issue as well and this fixed it for me. I'm posting a comment on the original showing what I need to fix the initial problem now.